# Function similar to Lua's nn.Identity()() in tensorflow

Tags: lua, tensorflow

Hello can some one please suggest a similar function to Lua's nn.Identity()() that can be used in Tensorflow.

Comment: There is no `Identity()` in pure Lua.

Answer (score 0):

There is [`tf.identity(x)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops/control_flow_operations#identity) which creates a new (named) node of the same content as `x`.